# Node.js writing jpeg file in multipart/form-data form on HTTP POST using express

Tags: node.js, encoding, http-headers, url-encoding

I have a node.js server that is receiving content from an iOS application. The content is in two parts: 1. json and 2. jpeg. I am trying to write the jpeg to a file that I can then pull up in a browser. It seems pretty straight-forward, but when I write the buffer from the req.body.imagedata to a file, it is a corrupt file.

Here is the first part of the jpeg from hexdump on the iPhone

```
0000000 **ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49** 46 00 01 01 00 00 01
0000010 00 01 00 00 ff e1 00 58 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d
0000020 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 02 01 12 00 03 00 00 00 01
```

Here is the Charles Proxy output from the iPhone Simulator. So, it is being transmitted from the iPhone correctly.

```
00000060  69 6e 61 72 79 0d 0a 0d 0a **ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a**   inary          J
00000070  **46 49** 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e1 00   FIF             
00000080  58 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00   XExif  MM *
```

Here is the tcpdump output on the server running node.

```
0000370 **d8ff e0ff 1000 464a 4649** 0100 0001 0100
0000380 0100 0000 e1ff 5800 7845 6669 0000 4d4d
0000390 2a00 0000 0800 0200 1201 0300 0000 0100
```

The server-side node tcpdump shows the correct header information coming across to the node.js server.

```
?ò?
?u???????
8?8w
?u??????????%? ??
8?8??L?|?Q??
?u??????????%? O|
8?8??L?POST /screenw/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ec2-103-22-8-3.compute-1.amazonaws.com:4914
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=01947848929231
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A3i1td3wlRo8dqrFETNTcbUBV.h4EPihMhJTOdlSBmIog3xm3C%2FvTWVyD4eBBw2Fige6o
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 37297
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Teachbits/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/12.2.0

|?Q??
?u???????%? ??
8?8??L?--01947848929231
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imagedata"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
....IMAGE DATA HERE.....
```

But the hexdump of the jpg that is written on the node.js side is wrong:

```
0000000 bfef efbd bdbf bfef efbd bdbf 1000 464a
0000010 4649 0100 0001 0100 0100 0000 bfef efbd
0000020 bdbf 5800 7845 6669 0000 4d4d 2a00 0000
```

Here is the code that receives the POST request and writes to a jpeg file.

```
app.post('/screenw/', function (req, res, next) {

    require("fs").writeFile("./http_image_64.jpg", req.body.imagedata, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('It\'s saved!');
            });
```

And when I print out the size of the buffer on both the iPhone simulator and the node server, the sizes do not match:

iPhone: image content is **32661** long

node.js req.body.imagedata raw image - **31679**

I believe the problem lies in one of 2 areas:

1. how Connect is parsing the jpeg section of the http body and handing it back to my server.js. i.e., I am providing the wrong Content-Type or other header information
2. how I am taking the req.body.imagedata writing it to the jpg file. i.e., I have the encoding and associated logic incorrect.

Any ideas on how to get this to work? I am stuck.

[EDITED]

Here is the objective-c code that constructs the http request:

```
//creating the url request:
tbImgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"screenw/" relativeToURL:[cts web_service]];
NSMutableURLRequest *tbImgReq2 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tbImgUrl];
[tbImgReq2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"01947848929231";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[tbImgReq2 setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[tbImgReq2 setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"enctype"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([imgVector screenImage], 1.0); // 0.0 - 1.0 l to h

// setting up the body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// append the photo image
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imagedata\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n", @"image/jpeg"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:imageData];

// append the json data
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"jsondata\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *reqData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sendPayload
                                                  options:0
                                                    error:nil];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:reqData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[tbImgReq2 setHTTPBody:body];
tbImgConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:tbImgReq2
                                                  delegate:self
                                          startImmediately:YES];
```

Comment: You should use `req.files.imagedata`

Answer (score 0):

you could use express js ...

submit with the correct encoding rules and then access through node js (Via the express library) via req.files, its been pretty reliable for me

Comment: Sorry. I put it in the title but forgot to include in the post, that I was using express. Unfortunately, with multipart/form-data (one part is image/jpeg and the other part is json), Express is returning the image as a field instead of a file. So, I receive back 2 fields from express js. The json looks correct, but the jpeg image is incorrect. Have you been able to use express with multipart successfully?

Comment: here is how i do it currently:

 enctype="multipart/form-data" (as the form enctype)

fs.readFile(req.files.photo_image.path, function (err, data) {
  var newPath = __dirname + "filename";

fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {


... you should be able to use req.files.imagedata to write to file as well however (Rather than reading data from the disk)

Can you post some of your application code for how you submit the file? (so we can check you are sending in the correct format). The fact the image data is part of the body seems wrong ...

Comment: Thanks for that. I was not aware of the enctype. So, I added that to the formatting of the message, but imagedata is still appearing within the req.body.imagedata. When I try to write the req.files.imagedata, it just writes 'undefined' to the file. I agree it is how I am structuring the message within the iOS environment. I have console.log statements all throughout the formidable code but still cannot figure it out! I will add the code I am using within the iOS app above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok I cant see any problems in your application code compared to other code examples on the web ... one thing I have come across is a simple library

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

check the section "Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest"

It looks like a nice library

Comment: Thanks for checking. I will install that library tonight and see how it goes. As a fallback I will send over two separate requests, one for the JSON and one for the image. Although not ideal, it will work for now. I'll give an update later.